# MVP pattern. Is it a good practice to inject all presenter's dependencies in a constructor of the presenter?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, mvp, dagger-2

I want my code to be testable and flexible and I cannot make a choice whether I need to pass all dependencies explicitly to a constructor of a presenter or it's better to pass only View interface to a constructor and inject all dependencies in it.

Answer (score 3):

It is a desirable pattern.

Every time you have access to object constructor, you should inject dependencies in constructor or other methods. `@Inject` annotation is indended mainly to be used inside object, that are not created by you.

When injecting all dependencies in constructor, during tests you pass all your dependencies to your model during initialisation. Therefore every test might contain different dependencies and different instance of created class. That is also the aim of unit tests - provide a sandbox for every test.

It is also easier to mock dependencies with `Mockito`.

Remember, that in unit tests, you don't have dependency any framework configured. A unit test usually contains created model and nothing more. Everything must be created by you (or mocked by framework)

Here is a sample unit test that proves the statement above:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class GetAreasUseCaseTest {
    @Mock ApiManager mApiManager;
    @Mock DatabaseManager mDatabaseManager;

    private GetAreasUseCase mGetAreasUseCase;

    @Rule
    public final RxSchedulersOverrideRule mOverrideSchedulersRule = new RxSchedulersOverrideRule();

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mGetAreasUseCase = new GetAreasUseCase(mApiManager,
                mDatabaseManager);
        doReturn(Observable.empty())
                .when(mDatabaseManager)
                .insertAreas(any(Area.class));
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetAreasUseCaseApiInteraction() throws Exception {
        TestSubscriber<List<Area>> testSubscriber = new TestSubscriber<>();
        setCorrectApiResponse();
        boolean input = true;
        Observable testedObservable = mGetAreasUseCase.build(input);
        testedObservable.subscribe(testSubscriber);
        verify(mApiManager).getAreas(anyLong());
    }
}
```

As you can see the structure of the test is very clear. It is well known, what is mocked and which object is tested.  You have the control of the behaviour of dependencies.

If you plan to do only instrumentation tests, then you are provided with the `ApplicationContext` in tests and `Dagger` is properly initialised. There is no difference here. Of course you might still emulate `Module`'s and `Component`'s behaviour and provide custom object's Mocks instead of real classes ([Example](https://github.com/ribot/ribot-app-android/tree/master/app/src/commonTest/java/io/ribot/app/test/common/injection))

Comment: Many thanks for the great answer! Also there can be a small drawback if you have a base UseCase for all UseCases in your app and you need to add a new dependency to it, then you have to change all its subclasses and many modules in order to provide the new dependency.

Answer (score 0):

its not a bad practice but its hard to change the code in later changes. what if you want to add a new dependency for presenter ? then you have to change almost everything in your code.

what you are going to do actually is called Dependency Injection and the best practice is to do Dependency Injection, is using libraries like Dagger.

i think Dagger is the most powerful Dependency Injection library up to now. you will write some methods for providing your dependencies and Dagger will provide them for you whenever you want them using a @inject Annotation. for a complete instruction see this link:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Dagger/article.html

Comment: Yes, I know. I'm afraid that my question is misunderstood. I meant is it good to provide dependencies as constructor parameters or it's better to have a constructor without any parameters and inject all the dependencies with component.inject(this)?

Comment: its better to use Dagger for all your injections because of what I told (you will need to change all code when a dependency is added). Dagger will generate all these code for you and in case of chaging not much code needs to be changed. even from point of performance adding more variables to constructor will cuase overhead and is not good. 
dont send your dependency in constructor !!

Comment: and what about mocking dependencies for testing? Is it very difficult to do with such approach?

Comment: with dagger+mvp+retrofit+mockito you can easily mock dependencies. you can mock your retrofit interface by providing a mock interface in a new module rather than main module providing your retrofit interface. see the link below for a great sample me and my friend made: https://github.com/mmirhoseini/trakt.tv